# Screen shot feature in android

Tags: android, screenshot, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

How to disable the screen shot feature from the application in ice cream sandwich android devices ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Means ? You want to disable the Default Screen Shot features for your app. right ??

Comment: yes..i need to disable this feature for a particular app.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add this line in your activity class. This will do the trick.

```
     //This disables screen shot to be taken for current activity
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

You may want to have a look on this [Link](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html)